# Can we convert a string variable to long or viceversa in android?

Tags: android

Is it possible to convert a string variable to long or a long variable to string type in android?
 If so how can I achieve that? Please help me regarding this....

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this....:)

String res=Long.toString(longValue);
long result=Long.parseLong(stringValue);

Answer (score 3):

Yes, easily:

```
long aLong = Long.parseLong(aString);
String aString = Long.parseLong(aLong);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try some thing like this:

long myLong = Long.parseLong(str);

Answer (score 1):

```
long long_variable = Long.parseLong(your_string);
```

It will work fine as far as you string is long compatible else it will throw parse Exception

```
String str = new Long(yout_long_variable).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Long.html#Long(java.lang.String) to construct a new long based on a string.

And http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Long.html#toString() to get a String from a long.